# issue installing matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

I am trying to install matplotlab in python from within Pycharm. I am using the inbuilt interpreter > pip > install matplotlib but I am getting the following error

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
    runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 206, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.prepare import RequirementPreparer
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions import (
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' from 'pip._internal.distributions.source' (C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\source\__init__.py)
```

The suggested solution is to install via the command line when I try this I am told that

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (3.2.0rc1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.18.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib) (1.14.0)
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be ?

thanks

Comment: Try to activate your virtual environment and then do pip install

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ImportError%3A+cannot+import+name+SourceDistribution